# How can I change icon for Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, developer-tools

As you probably know, Chrome Dev Tools has the same icon as browser itself. In order, to increase productivity I would like to change it's icon, so it will be easier to find it in the taskbar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried searching the interwebs for an answer and found nothing. I'm amazed there hasn't been an answer to this yet. We can't be the only people annoyed by this! Internet Explorer and Edge also use the same icon for their undocked dev tools window. Madness!

Comment: Found some past activity 2013, but looks like it was dropped:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=245766 - maybe someone can re-activate?

Comment: @Kirill kindly review my answer and accept if it meets your needs so I can obtain my elusive Necromancer badge :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Give this a try:

1. Open up Chrome and then open up developer tools in another window so that you have two Chrome icons on your taskbar. Right click the devtools one and Pin to taskbar.
2. Right click on the newly pinned icon, right click on Google Chrome (2) and properties.
   [image: PICKLE RIIIIIIIICK!!!]
3. Under Shortcut->Change Icon, pick something else. Then 'OK' out.
4. You'll need to restart explorer.exe, so open Windows Task manager, kill explorer.exe and restart it.

[image: Kill Explorer]
[image: Open Explorer]

5. You'll now see two different icons.
   [image]
6. Do this: Start regular Chrome. Then CTRL+Shift+i and it *should* open devtools as the new icon.

Unfortunately, clicking the devtools icon initially will not open devtools on startup. Supposedly you can change the properties to start using chrome.exe --args --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs but I was unable to make that work.

YMMV with your operating system but this works with Windows 7. Hope that helps.

Note: If you're using Windows 10, you won't see explorer in the task manager by default, you have to click "More details" on the bottom and switch to the "Details" tab.

Alternatively, open PowerShell and type:

```
Get-Process explorer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Stop-Process
```

This will kill explorer, and windows will automatically restart it

Comment: Is there any way to do same for Linux/Ubuntu?

Comment: @Richard nice joke!

Comment: probably not a joke.  chrome is out on linux/ubuntu

Comment: what about MacOS? I'd give this half a thumbs up.

Comment: If you're using windows 10, you wont see explorer in the task manager - open powershell and type:

Answer (score 1):

This answer may be a nice work around for non-Windows users who are debugging from Visual Studio Code. It uses Chrome's Canary build for debugging. It has a different icon so telling it apart from regular Chrome should be easy.

This answer talks about setting the executable to Canary which is easily distinguishable from regular Chrome. You will need to download the Canary version of Chrome first.

settings.json:

```json
"runtimeExecutable": "canary"
```

[How to configure Visual Studio Code debugger to use Chrome Canary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37047805/how-to-configure-visual-studio-code-debugger-to-use-chrome-canary)

[image]