# How to configure Visual Studio Code debugger to use Chrome Canary?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, visual-studio-code

I'm working on multiple projects simultaneously, and for one of them I want to use Chrome Canary to debug my application in Visual Studio Code.

so for Stable Chrome i have

```
{
        "name": "Launch Chrome",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "url": "http://localhost:7246/",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "--new-window",
            "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
        ],
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/app/"
}
```

Is there any easy way to configure in launch.json to use Chrome Canary on a separate debugging port (9223 for example), so I would be able to use Chrome Stable with debugging port 9222 for all the other things?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use the `runtimeExecutable` property to specify the path to the Chrome version you want to test with, in combination with `runtimeArgs`, specifying a different debugging port for that configuration. The `configurations` property in `launch.json` allows you to specify an array of configurations.

I haven't looked at VS Code myself, so cannot verify this, but there is some useful information here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug

**Update**
You can use an environment variable path instead of an absolute path.

In Command Prompt, try something like this to create the environment variable:

```
set CHROME_PATH=C:/Users/[USER]/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome SxS/Application
```

In the config file, the path can be referenced like this:

```
${env.CHROME_PATH}/chrome.exe
```

Check out https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_variable-substitution for more details.

Comment: thanks! Do you know if you can somehow use system environment vars in the config paths?

Comment: I added an update to my solution after discovering that you can use variable substitution. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 10):

For me a working version for Chrome Canary was

```
{
        "name": "Chrome Canary",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "url": "http://localhost:7246/",
        "port": 9223,
        "runtimeExecutable": "${env.USERPROFILE}/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome SxS/Application/chrome.exe",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "--new-window",
            "--remote-debugging-port=9223"
        ],
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/app/"
}
```

Comment: To append to the above answer, value "canary" for property "runtimeExecutable" is sufficient for launching in Canary.

Answer (score 6):

You can just add:

```
 "runtimeExecutable": "canary",
```