# Chrome debugging tools tab icon

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to change the 'Chrome Developer Tools' tab to have a new icon, as opposed to the normal chrome icon.

The reason for this is obvious. I want to have a chrome icon for the website and a new icon for the Developer tools so i can easily swap between them in the 
'Windows Taskbar'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change icon for Chrome Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496886/how-can-i-change-icon-for-chrome-developer-tools)